# Multiple pivots within a MYSQL table

Tags: mysql

I have the following setup for my database:

```
create table spooner_pec
(
  id int,
  year varchar(20),
  policy_number int,
  primary_name varchar(200),
  experience_rate decimal(10,2),
  mco_name varchar(200)
);
```

with these values being inserted:

```
insert into spooner_pec values
(1,'2009',183586,'ZBIN LANDSCAPING INC', 1.22, 'GENEX CARE FOR OHIO'),
(1,'2011',183586,'ZBIN LANDSCAPING INC', 0.93, 'COMPMANAGEMENT HEALTH SYSTEMS, INC.'),
(1,'2012',183586,'ZBIN LANDSCAPING INC', 0.92, 'HEALTH MANAGEMENT SOLUTIONS, INC.'),
(1,'2013',183586,'ZBIN LANDSCAPING INC', 0.50, 'CAREWORKS'),
(1,'2014',183586,'ZBIN LANDSCAPING INC', 0.47, 'UNIVERSITY HOSPITALS COMPCARE'),
(1,'2010',183586,'ZBIN LANDSCAPING INC', 1.27, 'SHEAKLEY UNICOMP')
```

The query that I have working so far is this:

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'max(case when year = ',
      year,
      ' then experience_rate end) AS `',
      year, '-Pen`'
    ) ORDER BY year
  ) INTO @sql
FROM
  spooner_pec;
SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT policy_number, primary_name, ', @sql, ' 
                  FROM spooner_pec 
                   GROUP BY policy_number');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

So after a previous question on here and some research I have finally gotten this pivot work correctly.  I am basically just taking all of the individual years and making them columns instead of rows.

So I have one row for each company and then a year-pen column for each year.  Now I need to also have a year-mco column the same way, where in my statement do I add this in?

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c2b88/9)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SET @sql2 = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'max(case when year = ',
      year,
      ' then experience_rate end) AS `',
      year, '-Pen`'
    ) ORDER BY year
  ) INTO @sql
FROM
  spooner_pec;

SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'max(case when year = ',
      year,
      ' then mco_name end) AS `',
      year, '-Mco`'
    ) ORDER BY year
  ) INTO @sql2
FROM
  spooner_pec;
SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT policy_number, primary_name, ', @sql, ', ', @sql2, ' 
              FROM spooner_pec 
               GROUP BY policy_number');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Comment: I kid you not I have tried this so many different options, but I didn't put a comma string between the 2 variables, makes so much sense now /facepalm.  Thank you!